# Managing Proxy Username/Password with Apache HTTPClient

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

When accessing a secured Proxy Server, I believe that good security practice would like the application to obtain the username/password and then encrypt it as soon as possible.  Ideally this would be one-way encryption.  However, when using HTTPClient, all the example usage is of the form:

```
credsProvider.setCredentials(
    new AuthScope(targetHost.getHostName(), targetHost.getPort()),
    new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password"));
```

Where 'username' and 'password' are the clear text versions.  Is there any API and/or usage that supports utilization via (some type of) encrypted variant?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to secure? What about https?

Comment: @fateddy - I am not trying to secure anything, nor use https.  Rather, trying to write code to plug into an existing customer(s) infrastructure that requires access via an authenticated Proxy Server (may be hardware proxy or software).  I would prefer to keep the unencrypted form of the password in code for as little time as possible, but I don't see how to do that effectively with HTTP Client.  Does that make any more sense?

Comment: Not exactly sure what your security concerns are. Are looking for some kind of token-based authentication? If then you are heavily depending on your customers' infrastructure.

Comment: It's me, but I don't know how to explain in better terms.  The usage model I see in all the various HTTP Client examples use both username and password in an unencrypted form.  This means that they either need to be stored that way or programmatically decrypted.  I would like to avoid doing either one of these if at all possible.